# Cannot convert undefined or null to object Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to make a filter method this method works well but I have an error: `cannot convert undefined or null to object that I cannot solve`

**example json**

```
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
  hideString: [], // filter method hide this element
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
```

}

**card.components.ts**

```
    @Input() toto: ISummary[] = []
    
    getKeys() {
     Object.keys(this.toto).filter(key => this.toto[key].lenght > 0)
     // in my console I have the following error: cannot convert undefined or null to object 
        the error comes from this line
    }
    
    totoa(keys:string){
     return this.toto[key]
    }
```

**card.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let keys of getKeys()">
 {{keys}}
  <div *ngFor="let values of totoa(keys)">
    {{values}}
  </div
</div
```

**home.components.ts**

```
public result: string = '';

public toto?: Observable<ISummary[]>; // maybe the problem comes from Here I have ternary operator '?'


ngOnInit() {
 this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params = > {
  let bigramme = params.get('bigramme');
  this.result = bigramme as string;
  getSummary();
 }
}

getSummary() {
 this.toto = this.sumService.getAllSummary(this.result);
}
```

Comment: The `this.toto[key]` maybe be the cause of it

Comment: this syntax is weird for me: `this.summarykeys.Object.keys(this.toto)`. you don't need `this.summarykeys` just use `Object.keys(yourobject)`

Comment: Also note that `toto` is array and keys of array is `0,1`,...` .

Comment: I updated my code with your advice

Comment: I would suggest you to start from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: What do you want to check in your array?

Comment: do you need all keys in array of object?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi the current json sometimes returns empty tables that I display in my html so the filter method filters all that so that I don't have empty tables that are displayed

Comment: Can you make a `stackblitz` code? with runnable code It's easy to help you

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi do you need all keys in array of object ? yes exactly

Comment: No some keys is ok. runnable code is more important than all keys

Comment: I don't know how to make stackblitz do you have the answer to my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235046/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-herve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cannot convert undefined or null to object Angular` error is occurred when you try `Object.keys(null)`. So you can check the object you want to pass to `object.keys`.

**But**

It seems you want to show some data in your html based on `key/value`, so there is a `keyvalue` pipe for this purpose and no need to extra code such as `totoa` methods.

And for hiding empty value simply use `[hidden]`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testObject | keyvalue" [hidden]="item.value.length == 0">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b>

    <div *ngFor="let item1 of item.value">
        Value: <b>{{item1}}</b>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo-ych9pz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is working sample

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it before using `toto` object.

The ? can also be used to null/undefined issue, like :

```
this.toto[key]?.something(); // will not throw error if toto[key] is not defined
```

But I think you are trying to get keys of toto before setting it, so I suggest you soemthing like :

```
public summarykeys: string[] = [];
    
@Input() toto: ISummary[] = []
    
getKeys() {
    return this.toto ? this.summarykeys.Object.keys(this.toto).filter(key => this.toto[key].lenght > 0) : [];
}
    
totoa(keys: string){
    return this.toto[key]
}
```